# Using image resources which don't comply to Android's naming scheme

Tags: android, resources, naming

I need to use image resources from an iOS application that I'm porting to Android. Unfortunately they all have dashes in the file name, which causes errors.

I can't rename the resources because they're shared with the iOS codebase, and having duplicate resources is a no-go.

Is there a way I can get around this naming requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to get around the naming requirement, but you could use symlinks.

(I'm a bit confused, though, and kind of assume you must already be either copying the files or using symlinks. How else could you build both your Android and iOS apps, given the different directory structures required for each?)

Comment: Just pulling the image resources from the iOS repo. I can't change their names though. Anyway I checked with the devs and it turns out I'm allowed to change the resource names and push them up to the Android repo. So I just need a script to rename them and put them into the workspace after pulling changes. Thanks.

Comment: @Glitch That's great! You should probably either accept my answer or delete your question, so as not to leave this as an unanswered question.